# Partial Fraction Decomposition When Denominator Has an Irreducible Factor of Degree 2

Tags: polynomials, factoring, partial-fractions

When doing partial fraction decomposition, there are three cases:

**Case 1: Denominator has distinct linear factors.**

$f(x) = \dfrac{P(x)}{(x - a_1)...(x - a_k)} = \dfrac{A}{x - a_2} + \dfrac{B}{x - a_k}$ where $a_1, ..., a_k$ are pairwise distinct.

**Case 2: Denominator has repeated linear factors.**

$f(x) = \dfrac{P(x)}{(x - a)^c} = \dfrac{B_1}{x - a} + ... + \dfrac{B_c}{(c - a)^c}$

**Case 3: Denominator has an irreducible factor of degree 2:**

$f(x) = \dfrac{P(x)}{(x - a)(x^2 + bx + c)} = \dfrac{A_1}{x - a} + \dfrac{C_1x + C_2}{x^2 + bx + c}$

In cases 1 and 2, the numerators are all given constant placeholders ($A, B$), but in case 3, the numerator is given a polynomial of degree one as the placeholder ($C_1x + C_2$). I'm curious as to why this is the case. What is the difference between case 1 and 2 and 3 that necessitates this difference in the numerator? What is the reasoning behind this?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to elaborate on this.

Comment: See the Related questions to yours, probably visible in a pane on the right side of your browser window.

Comment: I would do this if I were you.  try a basic example.  Try and decompose  $$\frac{1}{(x-1)(x^2-x+1)}=\frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{B}{x^2-x+1}$$  See what happens when you try and solve.  Consider you can only have two summands since you only have two factors.  What does that mean for the numerators?

Comment: @AveryJessup It seems that I only get one of the partial fractions --  $\dfrac{1}{(x - 1)(x^2 - x + 1)} = \dfrac{1}{x - 1}$?

Comment: Indeed.  If you have any linear algebra, you would call this system inconsistent, since of the impossibility to get singular values.  You have three equations and only 2 unknowns.  That sets up issues...  So you need a third unknown, but with only two fractions, it must be in the numerator of one of the two.  But if your third unknown is only a constant, two constants added yield one.  So the third unknown must be the coefficient of a higher degree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will offer a few explanations (some of which are obviously related, but may be more intuitive from one point of view than another.

### "Because you need it"

One obvious thing to do is to try without and see what happens. You have, multiplying up and equating coefficients,
$$ 1 = (x^2+2bx+c)A_1 + (x-a)P(x), $$
where $P(x)$ is the numerator of the quadratic fraction. If it's constant, there's no way to eliminate the $A_1 x^2$ without (absurdly) taking $A_1=0$, so the left-hand side would not be constant. If you take $P(x)=C_1x+C_2$, you *can* get rid of the $x^2$ term.

### Asymptotic behaviour

For very large $x$, $x-a \approx x $, $x^2 + 2bx+c \approx x^2$: only the highest-degree terms are important. But this means that
$$ \frac{1}{(x-a)(x^2+2bx+c)} \approx \frac{1}{x^3}, $$
while
$$ \frac{A_1}{x-a}+\frac{C_2}{x^2+2bx+c} \approx \frac{A_1}{x}. $$
Since both sides need to have the same asymptotics, there needs to be an extra term to cancel the $A_1/x$.

### Pretend the denominator is factorisable

Finally, we can pretend the denominator is actually factorisable, and see what happens when we put the fractions back together.
$$ \frac{A}{x-a_1} + \frac{B}{x-a_2} = \frac{(A+B)x-a_1 B + a_2 A}{(x-a_1)(x-a_2)}, $$
so if $A+B \neq 0$, there is an $x$ term anyway. (This is actually legitimate, since the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra says any quadratic has two complex roots. Note the $x$ term does not involve the roots at all anyway.) It would be weird if this property didn't carry over to unfactorisable denominators, since we can always just not factor a factorisable quadratic when doing partial fractions.